# TSQL - Select values with same IS

Tags: t-sql

have a view like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFJjc.png)

The record "NDocumento" is populated only in the first row of a transaction by design. These rows are grouped by the column "NMov" which is the ID.

Since this is a view, I would like to populate each empty "NDocumento" record with the corresponding value contained in the first transaction through a SELECT statement.

As you can see by the picture this is MS-SQL Server 2008, so the lack of LAG makes the game harder.

I would immensely appreciate any help,

thanks

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Please edit you question to include all of the relevant information as text. Otherwise you might get a slightly skewed photograph of a query as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
        T1.NDocumento
    ,   T2.NMov
    ,   T2.NRiga
--  ,   T2. Rest of the fields      
FROM    NDocumentoTable T1
JOIN    NDocumentoTable T2  ON  T2.NMov = T1.NMov
WHERE   T1.NRiga = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used LAG() over the partition of NMov,Causale by based on your data. You cna change the partition with your requirement.   The logic is you get the previous value if the NDocument is empty for the given partition.

```
CREATE TABLE myTable_1
  (
   NMov int
  ,NRiga int 
  ,CodiceAngrafica varchar(100)
  ,Causale varchar(100)
  ,DateRegistration date
  ,DateDocumented date
  ,NDocument varchar(100)
  )

 INSERT INTO  myTable_1  VALUES (5133, 1, '', 'V05', '01/14/2021', '01/14/2021', 'VI-2100001')
   ,(5133, 2, '', 'V05', null, null, '')
   ,(5134, 1, '', 'V05', '01/14/2021', '01/14/2021', 'VI-2100002')
   ,(5134, 2, '', 'V05', null, null, '')


  SELECT 
    NMov
   ,NRiga 
   ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(NDocument,'') = '' 
        THEN LAG(NDocument) OVER  (PARTITION BY NMov,Causale  ORDER BY NMov) 
    ELSE NDocument END AS [NDocument]  
 FROM myTable_1
```

[image: Result]